# Does the present fit in this case

Tags: present-tense

January  1st **is** on Saturday next year  or january will be on Saturday next year

I think present fits because it is something that can't be changed . So what is the better solution, is it only a point a view of the speaker

Comment: There is no "better" issue here. Both versions are fine, and mean exactly the same thing. But see [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+next+week%2Cwill+be+next+week&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20next%20week%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwill%20be%20next%20week%3B%2Cc0) showing how in recent decades there's been a strong trend towards ***simplification*** (just use Present Tense wherever you can get away with it).

Comment: Yes, the present tense is often used for future events, especially those that are natural or regular.  This is fairly basic grammar.

Answer (score -1):

`January 1st is on Saturday next year` is fine in this case, because what is implied is:
`January 1st is going to be on Saturday next year` so not really present tense at all.

`January the 1st will be on Saturday next year` is fine too - note that in British English `the` is normal usage, as I have shown here.

Comment: Or to put it another way: English does not have a future tense. A number of different forms are used to express future meaning, one of which is the so-called present tense.

Comment: There can certainly be *semantic* differences relating to how we express "future" in a language that doesn't support it through morphological inflection. So our choice in, for example, *Be careful! That animal **bites / will bite / is going to bite*** is to a considerable extent governed by both the actual context and the exact meaning / nuance intended by the speaker.